# Jabber integration in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, chat, xmpp

I'm looking for an AJAX-enabled web client for Jabber. I found some, but they look hard to integrate with ASP.NET.

Some of them were not even tested in IE.

I'm trying to make an Facebook-like chat client, any suggestion is welcomed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this jabbar library for .NET:

http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

Or here if you need a ready-to-go solution for your website:

http://www.hotscripts.com/

Comment: Thanks, looks nice. Although it would be better one with ASP.NET integration, cause it would not be simple to create the whole client integration (the ajax stuff)

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful in hotscripts.com. Did you see something there?

Comment: Yes, but not in ASP.NET category. For example this one: http://www.claros.org/web/showProduct.do?id=2

Comment: Also take a look at this one:
http://code.google.com/p/ijab/